# Refreshing a CKEditor5 widget upon model changes

Tags: widget, ckeditor5

I have a custom schema element with a text attribute node that renders as a widget for the `editingDowncast`:

```
conversion.for( 'editingDowncast' )
  .add( downcastElementToElement({
    model: 'myModelElement',
    view: (modelElement, viewWriter) => {
      return createMyModelWidget( modelElement, viewWriter, 'Label' );
    }
  } )
);

function createMyModelWidget( modelElement, writer, label ) {
  const content = modelElement.getAttribute('content')
  const placeholder = writer.createText( content );
  const container = writer.createContainerElement( 'div', { class: 'my-model-element--widget' } );

  writer.insert( ViewPosition.createAt( container ), placeholder );
  return toWidget( container, writer, label );
}
```

Through some external event (e.g., result from an external modal that configures the widget), the attribute is updated using `model.change`.

```
model.change(writer => {
  writer.setAttribute( 'attribute', 'whatever', widget );
  writer.setAttribute( 'content', 'new content', widget );
});
```

Now since its attribute changed, I would expect the widget to be re-rendered, however that is not the case. How can I manually trigger a refresh to ensure it is up-to-date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The refreshing of an view widget on model changes is handled by downcast conversion. I can see that you want convert a model attribute to a text contents of a `<div>`. I assume that the "attribute" attribute is a `<div>`s element attribute (like `data-attribute`). In such case you'll need set of converters:

1. Upcast

   - a single [element to element upcast converter](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_upcast-converters.html#static-function-upcastElementToElement) that will create `myModelElement` model element instance.
2. Downcast

   - an [element to element downcast converter](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_downcast-converters.html#static-function-downcastElementToElement) that will create `div` for newly inserted `myModelElment` into a model
   - a custom [attribute converter](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_downcastdispatcher-DowncastDispatcher.html#event-attribute) that will update `div` contents on attribute `content` changes
3. A two-way converter that will cover simple [attribute to attribute](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_conversion-Conversion.html#function-attributeToAttribute) conversion (both upcast & downcast).

ps.: I've used "downcast" instead of "editingDowncast" to not define the downcast conversion for "editingDowncast" and "dataDowncast" separately.

```js
// Required imports:
// import { toWidget } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget/src/utils';
// import { downcastElementToElement } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/conversion/downcast-converters';
// import { upcastElementToElement } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/conversion/upcast-converters';
// import ViewPosition from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/position';
// import ViewRange from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/range';

const conversion = editor.conversion;
const model = editor.model;
const schema = model.schema;

// Define model element and allow attributes on it.
schema.register( 'myModelElement', {
    allowWhere: '$block',
    allowAttributes: [ 'content', 'attribute' ],
    isObject: true
} );

// Simple attribute to attribute converter two-way converter
// - for upcast it will read "data-attribute" property of div and put it into model's "attribute" attribute
// - for downcast it will update "data-attribute" on changes in "attribute".
conversion.attributeToAttribute( {
    model: {
        name: 'myModelElement',
        key: 'attribute'
    },
    view: {
        key: 'data-attribute'
    }
} );

// Define upcast conversion:
conversion.for( 'upcast' ).add( upcastElementToElement( {
    model: ( viewElement, modelWriter ) => {
        const firstChild = viewElement.getChild( 0 );
        const text = firstChild.is( 'text' ) ? firstChild.data : '(empty)';

        return modelWriter.createElement( 'myModelElement', { content: text } );
    },
    view: {
        name: 'div',
        classes: 'my-model-element--widget'
    }
} ) );

// Define downcast conversion:
conversion.for( 'downcast' )
    .add( downcastElementToElement( {
        model: 'myModelElement',
        view: ( modelElement, viewWriter ) => {
            return createMyModelWidget( modelElement, viewWriter, 'Label' );
        }
    } ) )
    // Special conversion of attribute "content":
    .add( dispatcher => dispatcher.on( 'attribute:content', ( evt, data, conversionApi ) => {
        const myModelElement = data.item;

        // Mark element as consumed by conversion.
        conversionApi.consumable.consume( data.item, evt.name );

        // Get mapped view element to update.
        const viewElement = conversionApi.mapper.toViewElement( myModelElement );

        // Remove current <div> element contents.
        conversionApi.writer.remove( ViewRange.createOn( viewElement.getChild( 0 ) ) );

        // Set current content
        setContent( conversionApi.writer, data.attributeNewValue, viewElement );
    } ) );

function createMyModelWidget( modelElement, writer, label ) {
    const content = modelElement.getAttribute( 'content' );
    const container = writer.createContainerElement( 'div', { class: 'my-model-element--widget' } );

    setContent( writer, content, container );

    return toWidget( container, writer, label );
}

function setContent( writer, content, container ) {
    const placeholder = writer.createText( content || '' );
    writer.insert( ViewPosition.createAt( container ), placeholder );
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks! I was falsely expecting I could get by with rendering the widget top-down, and updating the entire widget through some event other than the immediate attribute change events. Still have to wrap my head around some of the approaches, but they turn out doing exactly what I would have wanted in the first place.